# How to add two images in a list item when using simple cursor adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

How to add two images in a list item when using simple cursor adapter. i tried override setViewImage by extending SimpleCursorAdapter class.For single image no proble. But how to add two images?

**MyFragment.java:**

```
geoAdapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listitem_cdf_geolist, c1, new String[] {DBConstants.LATITUDE,DBConstants.LONGITUDE,DBConstants.TOLERANCE,DBConstants.IMEI,DBConstants.IMEI}, new int[] {R.id.li_cdf_tv_latitude,R.id.li_cdf_tv_longitude,R.id.li_cdf_tv_tolerance,R.id.li_cdf_icon_georemove,R.id.li_cdf_icon_geoedit},0);
geoList.setAdapter(geoAdapter);
```

**In MySimpleCursorAdapter.java file:**

```
@Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView imageView, String imei) { 
        Log.i("simple", "text->"+imei);


        //Here how to set two images and set imei as tag for those images

        imageView.setTag(imei);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_edit);

        final ImageView myimageView=imageView;

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.i("simple", "clicked");
              String selectedIMEI = v.getTag().toString();
            }
        });

    }
```

**List Item Layout XML file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_stv_latitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/li_cdf_stv_latitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_tv_latitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/li_cdf_stv_latitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_stv_longitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/li_cdf_stv_latitude"
        android:layout_below="@id/li_cdf_stv_latitude"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/li_cdf_stv_longitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_tv_longitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/li_cdf_tv_latitude"
        android:layout_below="@id/li_cdf_tv_latitude"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/li_cdf_stv_longitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_stv_tolerance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/li_cdf_stv_longitude"
        android:layout_below="@id/li_cdf_stv_longitude"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/li_cdf_stv_tolerance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_tv_tolerance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/li_cdf_tv_longitude"
        android:layout_below="@id/li_cdf_tv_longitude"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/li_cdf_stv_tolerance" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_icon_georemove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/li_cdf_icon_georemove"
        android:onClick="removeGeofence" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/li_cdf_icon_geoedit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/li_cdf_icon_georemove"
        android:contentDescription="@string/li_cdf_icon_geoedit"
        android:onClick="editGeofence" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp" >
    </View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE :**

I tried to over ride on bindview. The images displayed for each list item. But If i set tag to each image,same tag applied to all images.Also remove icon onclick event only fires when click both edit and remove images.How to

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
        super.bindView(view, context, c);
        ImageView geoEditIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.li_cdf_icon_geoedit);
        geoEditIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_editvehicle);
        geoEditIcon.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.IMEI)));

    geoEditIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Log.i("geolist", "geoRemoveIcon clicked");
          String selectedIMEI = v.getTag().toString();
          Log.i("geolist", "geoRemoveIcon selectedIMEI->"+selectedIMEI);
        }
    });

    ImageView geoRemoveIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.li_cdf_icon_georemove);
    geoRemoveIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_removevehicle);
    geoRemoveIcon.setTag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.IMEI)));

    geoRemoveIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Log.i("geolist", "geoRemoveIcon clicked");
          String selectedIMEI = v.getTag().toString();
          Log.i("geolist", "geoRemoveIcon selectedIMEI->"+selectedIMEI);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to override method bindView. This will look like:

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
ImageView frst = (ImageView )view.findViewById(R.id.li_cdf_icon_georemove);
ImageView scnd = (ImageView )view.findViewById(R.id.li_cdf_icon_geoedit);
...
}
```